# Keras with Theano on GPU

Tags: theano, keras, theano-cuda

While trying to run my Keras code on GPU (CUDA installed), I am not able to execute the following statement, as has been suggested on many online references.

```
set THEANO_FLAGS="mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32" & python theanogpu_example.py
```

I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: Invalid value ("FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32") for configurati
on variable "mode". Valid options are ('Mode', 'DebugMode', 'FAST_RUN', 'NanGuar
dMode', 'FAST_COMPILE', 'DEBUG_MODE')
```

I have tried the other mode suggested as well from inside the code.

```
import theano
theano.config.device = 'gpu'
theano.config.floatX = 'float32'
```

I get the following error.

```
Exception: Can't change the value of this config parameter after initialization!
```

Apart from knowing how to make it run, I would also take this opportunity to ask a simpler question. How to know in Windows what is my device i.e. whether 'gpu' or 'gpu1' or 'gpu0'? I have tried all 3 for my case but it hasn't yielded result.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: could you give more information about your OS and your hardware specification?

Comment: Windows 7 enterprise 64 big , i7, 32GB RAM, nvidia Quadro K2100m

Comment: have you ever tried to use .theanorc file?

Comment: Yes I created the file and kept it in the %USERPROFILE%. It seemed to have worked in the sense of invoking the GPU but failed by giving error about graphics card can't be removed and the system froze. I think it's a driver problem with Keras

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using `THEANO_FLAGS` before run code, because the config variables cannot be changed after importing Theano, try this:

```
import os
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = "device=cuda,force_device=True,floatX=float32"
import theano
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), because they don't teach the solution.